# Bootstrap modal can't displayed inside <h:form>

Tags: xhtml, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap on my web application.
Now, I'd like to create a button and after clicking on it, a dialog is displayed.
This is done with success if my xhtml page doesn't contain **h:form**, but once my xhtml page presents **h:form** the model can't be displayed.

Bellow is the button:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Modals
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                Launch Demo Modal
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my xhtml page including the button of modal:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      template="/pages/indexTemplate.xhtml"> 

 <h:head>
     <title>SLEAM Book | Consult a Facebooker</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['icons/hki2.gif']}"/>
        <style>
   .ui-datatable thead th, .ui-datatable tbody td, .ui-datatable tfoot td {
      border-style: none;
        </style>
    </h:head>
 <h:body>
     <ui:composition template="indexTemplate.xhtml">
   <ui:define name = "content">
          <h:form>
              <h:outputText value="Add a Publication" styleClass="text-primary"/>
              <br/><br/>
              <h:inputText value="#{userBean.publicationContent}" styleClass="form-control"/>
              <br/>
              <p:commandButton value="Post" 
          action="#{userBean.createPublication}"
          styleClass="btn btn-primary"
          id="btn" ajax="true"/> 
     #{userBean.lps.size()}
     <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Modals
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                Launch Demo Modal
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     <br/><br/><br/>
     <div class="table-responsive">
         <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{userBean.lps}" tableStyleClass="table table-striped">
             <f:facet name="header">
                 List Of Publications
             </f:facet>
             <p:column headerText="Id">
                 <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
             </p:column>
             <p:column headerText="Title">
                 <h:outputText value="#{car.title}" />
             </p:column>
             <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
        <p:commandButton value="Post" 
               id="btn" 
               ajax="true"
              styleClass="btn btn-primary"/>
             </p:column>
         </p:dataTable>
      <p:dialog header="Car Info" widgetVar="carDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
             <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                 <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty userBean.selectedPublication}" columnClasses="label,value">
                     <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                     <h:outputText value="#{userBean.selectedPublication.id}" />
      
                     <h:outputText value="Title" />
                     <h:outputText value="#{userBean.selectedPublication.title}" />
                 </p:panelGrid>
             </p:outputPanel>
         </p:dialog>
     </div>   
    </h:form>
          </ui:define>
     </ui:composition>
 </h:body> 
</html>
```

The file **faces-config.xml** is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Have you please any idea about fixing this issue ?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you include what the jsf looks like

Comment: Hello @Sasang, I used jsf 2.2. I shared my full xhtml page as well as the file faces-config.xml on my updated question. Could you please take a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try like that:

```html
<p:commandLink value="Edit" styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#myModal').modal('show');" update=":myForm" immediate="true"/>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <h:form id="myForm">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Test Modal</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         Hello World
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                           </div>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot @saria for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i haven't done jsf in forever, but took some time recreating a sample jsf project based on your code, i got it working then i realized the solution is pretty trivial, nothing to do with jsf at all. In an html form, if you have a button and dont specify the type it will default to submit, so clicking on it will submit the form. Since you do not want that happening, you just want a modal to pop up and not POST anything, all you have to do is specify the type. Replace the button with this and it should work:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button">
  Launch Demo Modal
</button>
```